# HTML Source-Code rip-save?

Tags: javascript, html, security

i came across a js library (jsMovie) and wanted to see the example files, but it is really badly documented (usage), so i tried to download the authors page to look in the source-code. But when trying to do that, I've recognized that "view-source" wasn't giving the full code (almost 80% of the code did not appear).  (Tried in Chrome, Firefox)

So my question is, how can this be? Firebug is displaying everything propperly. At this moment i thought, that this could be as well a good way to prevent kiddies from ripping sites.

**here the page:** http://konsultaner.de/entwickler#Konsultaner

Hints are welcome

Comment: Right click -> inspect element (in Chrome) to see the generated HTML.

Comment: "View Source" will show you the original HTML response that your browser received.  However, it doesn't show you anything that's changed in the DOM client-side.  Debugging tools (such as Firebug, which you mention) will show you the current state of the DOM, the loaded resources (JavaScript files, CSS files, etc.), and so on.  What specifically are you looking for that isn't there?

Comment: @David I want to see how this plugin is initialized, which attributes the div should have and what the dependencies are. There is only the js code snippet, but not more.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the current source code, as interpreted by the browser. This can be done using an [*XMLSerializer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) on `document`.

```
var generatedSource = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

From there, if you want to open a page just showing the source, you could do

```
window.open('data:text/plain,'+encodeURIComponent(generatedSource), '_blank');
```

Comment: How can i use it, when i cannot access document? instead of document the url isn't working

Comment: I don't understand; I have no trouble running it on the page you asked about http://pastebin.com/yCZXLBZ1

Answer (score 0):

They are using AngularJS, a front-end javascript framework. That means almost all parts of the page are generated dynamically using javascript. Therefore, you can't see the page without javascript running (using view-source), but you can see the generated HTML via inspector.

If it is a static website (the javascripts and templates are all there), you can still 'rip' it. But not if it is a dynamic website, since all data and logic are 'fed' by the server.